# Getting IDX10803: Unable to create to obtain configuration error in azure VM. Locally working fine

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, identityserver4, azure-virtual-machine

I have hosted identityserver which is using self signed certificate in IIS in one my azure VM. This is ssl enabled site. This is using identityserver3 framework.

I am hosting asp.net core 2.0 webapi in the same VM and this is not ssl enabled.
Below is my setup on core 2.0 api side:

```
Startup.cs -> ConfigurationServices() {
            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                    .AddIdentityServerAuthentication(options =>
                    {
                        options.Authority = "https://localhost:44300/identity";
                        options.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                        options.ApiName = "web_api";
                        options.LegacyAudienceValidation = true;
                    });
}
```

Both were working fine locally with the above setup. But in the vm when i try to access the api, i am getting following error:

```
ERROR   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler - Exception occurred while processing message. - System.InvalidOperationException: IDX10803: Unable to obtain configuration from: 'https://localhost:44300/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.IO.IOException: IDX10804: Unable to retrieve document from: 'https://localhost:44300/identity/.well-known/openid-configuration'. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: A security error occurred
```

I made sure the self-signed certificate is available in

MMC->trused certifcates both in Current User and in Local Computer.

Self signed certificate is available in :

MMC-> Local Computer -> Personal Certificates
Local COmputer -> Trusted Root Certificates

MMC ->Current User -> Trusted Root Certificates

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36299959/idx10803-unable-to-create-to-obtain-configuration

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem, until I found out that the user, who is running the app pool, where IdentityServer is hosted, should have at least read permissions over the certificate.

> MMC ->Current User -> Trusted Root Certificates

This is giving the rights to your account, but check which is the app pool account and then, in the computer certificates:

> Right click on the certificate -> All Tasks -> Manage private keys

Also realized, that couldn't give such permissions to the `DefaultAppPoolIdentity` so I ended up using a separate account for this app pool.